# How to handle of responses of simultaneous Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending multiple simultaneous async Ajax call to the server and I am using same callback for all. I need to understand what will happen when simultaneous responses try to invoke callback function? or even if there are simultaneous responses trying to invoke single callback, will it be invoked one by one?

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: Each request/response will be handled one by one by the call-back function in the order the response comes in.